# Selenium Web Driver seems to skip driver.get() intermittently

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Web Driver test written in Java, targeting a Liferay site.

```
// Login
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
driver.findElement(By.id("_58_login")).sendKeys(login);
driver.findElement(By.id("_58_password")).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']")).click();

// Try to navigate to dashboard and expect error
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Liferay")));
driver.get(baseUrl + "/user/tm2/so/dashboard");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(., 'Not Found')]"));
```

The problem is that intermittently (~50% of the time), the test fails with exception `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h3[contains(., 'Not Found')]"}`

When watching the Web Driver's browser behavior during the test, what happens is that the login routine works as expected, clicking the "Sign In" button. But then once the page reaches the landing page, it hangs for 30 seconds (my implicit timeout setting), and throws the exception.

My suspicion is that the `driver.get(baseUrl + "/user/tm2/so/dashboard")` call is somehow skipped over. You can see I have setup a WebDriverWait to try to prevent the driver.get navigation from happening until the login routine is finished, but it doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I found out the problem is not Selenium related - it's a problem in the application itself where sometimes navigating to URLs just refreshes the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, change code to something like this instead:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
           .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
           .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, ElementNotFoundException.class);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Liferay")));
driver.get(baseUrl + "/user/tm2/so/dashboard");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[contains(., 'Not Found')]"));
```

Comment: This will help me for future reference, but I found out the problem is not Selenium related - it's a problem in the application itself where sometimes navigating to URLs just refreshes the current page. Also, you should add TimeUnit.SECONDS instead of just SECONDS for people who copy-paste this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the explicit timeout.  If the ExpectedCondition is not met, then FluentWait will retry.  That works better than a manual explicit timeout IMHO.   Lots of applications have the issue you are seeing... I have seen it lots of times and so its common.   Sometimes I extend LoadableComponent on my page objects to handle the flaky conditions a little nicer.